# Stepping through with F8 the code runs, stops in standard execution with F5

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, excel-formula, find

I've written a macro which sums numbers, grouping by year and by month based on our projection model.

It runs from start to end when stepping through with F8.
It stops immediately in standard execution with F5.

The first trouble is

> Runtime error 91

in

```
issmIndex = Range("A1:Z1").Find("ck.IssMon").Column  'issmIndex an integer
```

Originally I tried `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(...)` but had the same problem: runs in debug, but not in execute (`Error 1004` instead).

I considered it could have been an Excel version issue (the `Match` function has a different name in the Italian version). I switched to a more neutral `Find`, but still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the sheet name as well as the range `sheets("sheetname").range("a1:x1")`  Is it actually available to find?  Are you handling it not being found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have an error with a line that is a combination of several commands, try breaking it down into the individual steps.

For example, this works:

```
Sub findDemo()
  Const toFind = "blah"
  Dim rg As Range, f As Range
  Set rg = Range("A2:C5")
  Set f = rg.Find(toFind)
  If f Is Nothing Then
    Stop 'not found
  Else
    Debug.Print "found in column #" & f.Column
  End If
End Sub
```

Also see the example in the documentation for [`Range.Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Sometimes Excel *reads* code *faster* than executing, so when reading a command there is a previous one not finished. IT's weird but it happens a lot if your code does a lot of stuff and calculus.

Besides, when debugging, every command line is executed before reading next one, so you cannot detect this just debugging.

So if your code runs perfect when debugged but errors if executed as normal, try to add  the command `DoEvents` right before the problematic line. Something like this:

```
' your previous code
'
'
'
Doevents
issmIndex = Range("A1:Z1").Find("ck.IssMon").Column 'issmIndex an integer
'
'rest of your code
```

This commands *forces* Excel to make sure everything has been executed before reading. It's kind of like a checkpoint, something like *make sure you've done everything before going to next line*.

> [DoEvents
> function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function)